# Could not find a connected Android device

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, cucumber, appium

I am unable to launch the android emulator to run my automation script.

However my automation script works when I launch the android emulator manually from the `/Android/sdk/tools` directory using `emulator -avd Pixel_API_25 -port 5557`.

I want to be able to load the android emulator within my automation script.

Please see my env.rb file below.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'pry'
require 'appium_lib'

APP_PATH = '/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-class-booking-
mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app'

  desired_caps = {
      caps: {:platformName => "Android",
             :platformVersion => "7.1.1",
             :deviceName => "Pixel_API_25",
             :app => "/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-
             class-booking-
             mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-
             debug.apk",
             :appPackage => "com.android.settings",
             #:appActivity => ".Settings",
             :browserName =>''
             }

  }

@driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver
Appium.promote_appium_methods self.class

def server_url
  'http://localhost:8000/wd/hub'
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: which appium version are you using? did you try checking `launch AVD` option in the appium? if its not available, can you try adding `AVD` to your desired capabilities and recheck?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your desired capability . You need `avd` capability in order to start the emulator.

In java
`capabilities.setCapability("avd","AndroidTestDevice");`

In case of ruby, Any one of these two.

1. `avd: "AndroidTestDevice",`

   2. `:avd => "AndroidTestDevice",`

Your desired caps should something look like this

```
desired_caps = {
      caps: {:platformName => "Android",
             :platformVersion => "7.1.1",
             :deviceName => "Pixel_API_25",
             :app => "/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-
             class-booking-
             mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-
             debug.apk",
             :appPackage => "com.android.settings",
             `:avd => "AndroidTestDevice",`
             #:appActivity => ".Settings",
             :browserName =>''
             }

  }
```

On a side note, don't give a root directory as a file path to your application. This might later cause problems if you are using CI's , instead have a generic code where you only indicate, the `.apk` or `.app/.ipa` name.

Comment: Fantastic that brings up the simulator. Instead of `AndroidTestDevice` is used the device I created in Android Studio. However its not loading the app and giving me `Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)` how can I get the app to pop up and use the app?

Comment: btw, what are you having this code for? `APP_PATH = '/Users/shafiq.malik/Documents/Projects/nuff-class-booking-
mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app'` . Considering you are performing an android test

Comment: Yes I am I want to be able to test a android app.

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik You need to go to the appium and uncheck the launchable activity

Comment: appologies I am quite new to appium. How do I do that?

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: I am using `Version 1.0.2-beta.2 (1.0.2-beta.2)`

Comment: You have used # before the `:appactivity` in your desired capabilities. Can you remove that and check with correct `:appactivity`?

Comment: `:appActivity => ".Settings",` brings up the setting screen but not the app :-(

Comment: what is your app activity name? mention the required app_activity name or if you do not have, remove that from the desired capabilities and re-check

Comment: Apologies but where will I find this information? do you mean the app name?

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik Are you testing the settings app? if not, you need to ask the developer the package name. Try running it just with the package name without App_activity and let me know :)

Comment: 1. use 'appactivity' in stead of 'appActivity' and 'apppackage' in stead of 'appPackage' while setting Compatibility
2. Use absolute file path. i.e `app: (File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "abc.apk")),` in the desired capabilities.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!!! Just to understand why did you change `appActivity` and `appPackage` and the absolute path.

Comment: Using an absolute path is always good, if you have many CI machines integrated to your tests. Mentioning the root of the path, always leads the Appium to only look for that particular file in the specific root you gave. About `apppackage` and `appactivity` these are specific format that you have to write.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer in case this worked and solved your issue!